# wanted insights on score method of sklearn classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

There is a .score() function for classifiers that sklearn provides to us like LogisticRegression,DecisionTreeClassifier,etc.Does this score function returns the score on the basis of accuracy of its prediction?If yes then what about the cases where accuracy might not be the best parameter to evaluate the performance of the model?Is the score function self adjusting according to the use cases?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you can see from the documentation of LogisticRegression and DecisionTreeClassifier, the score method returns the "Mean accuracy of `self.predict(X)` wrt. `y`.". So, it does indeed return the accuracy of the predictions.

In cases where you want to use other metrics to evaluate a model's performance, you can use the metrics provided in the scikit-learn library which you can find on the [scikit-learn's website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics).

An example would be using F1 as a metric. You can have your true values `y_true` and your predicted values `y_pred`, then calling `f1_score(y_true, y_pred)` to get the F1 result.